# Cannot return 'null' from generic methods?

Tags: c#, .net, generics

I have a generic method like:

```
public T GetLevelElement<T>(string name) where T : ILevelElement
{
    //[...]
}
```

Which basically performs a lookup in a db and in some cases it does not (and cannot return) a result and I would like to return null.

However that's obviously not possible because of '*There is no implicit conversion between T and null*'. What should I do in this case?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

T cannot be null, because T could be a value type. Try returning default(T) or adding a class constraint to indicate that T can only be a reference type like so:

```
public T GetLevelElement<T>(string name) where T : ILevelElement, class
{
    [...]
}
```

Comment: In .NET 3.5 at least, the above should be `... where T : class, ILevelElement`.  The compiler chokes because it wants the `class` keyword to be first.

Answer (score 0):

Dustin Campbell is right. Another solution would be to return `default(T)`.

Comment: oh. I didn't see that he already told you about the default keyword. Ignore my answer.